# Is setState() optional for updating the state in Alt.js store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, alt.js

Yeah, I know that *`setState()` updates a Store's state and emit a change event to all subscribers*, but I find out that not everyone uses it and omit it when they update the state.

For example in the following [alt-todo repo](https://github.com/benstokoe/alt-todo/blob/master/js/stores/TodoStore.js), they don't use `setState()`:

```
class TodoStore {
    constructor() {
        this.bindActions(TodoActions);

        this.todos = {};
    }

    onCreate(text) {
        text = text.trim()
        if (text === '') {
            return false
        }
        // hand waving of course.
        const id = (+new Date() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999)).toString(36)
        this.todos[id] = {
            id: id,
            complete: false,
            text: text
        }
    }
}
```

However in the [official alt.js repo](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt) they use it:

```
class LocationStore {
    constructor() {
        this.bindAction(locationActions.updateLocation, this.onUpdateLocation);

      this.state = {
        city: 'Denver',
        country: 'US'
      };
    }

    onUpdateLocation(obj) {
        const { city, country } = obj
        this.setState({ city, country });
    }
}
```

**So I'm wondering what's the difference in the both ways?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't one, really:

> setState is used internally by Alt to set the state. You can override this to provide your own setState implementation. Internally, setState is an alias for Object.assign. setState must return an object.

http://alt.js.org/docs/createStore/#setstate

An example:
Let's say your state is:

```
{
  city: 'Denver',
  country: 'US',
}
```

The two ways of updating state:

```
this.setState({city: 'Colorado Springs'})
console.log(this.state) // {city: 'Colorado Springs', country: 'US' })

this.state = { city: 'Elbert' }
console.log(this.state) // state is {city: 'Elbert'}
```

As you can see, `this.state =` overwrites the state, while `this.setState()` merges the new state into the old. See [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/assign)

Comment: So if `this.setState()` is omitted, then it's called by default, right?

Comment: No. You will just overwrite you're entire state instead of merging it.

Comment: I also noticed that direct assigning state not always fires `emitChange() `